# error using python.connector by select ... where ... command

Tags: python, mysql

When I run this function some error occurs, but I have no idea what's wrong.

```
def insertVariblesIntoTable(newepc, newtimestamp):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='myDB',
                                             user='root',
                                             password='root')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO myTB(epc,time_stamp)  
                                SELECT newepc,newtimestamp
                                    FROM dual
                                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTB
                                                        WHERE epc=newepc 
                                                        AND time_stamp>NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MINUTE )"""
        cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
        connection.commit()
        print("Record inserted successfully into myTB table")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            # print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

error:

Failed to insert into MySQL table 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'newepc' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to access a column named "newepc" which doesn't exist.
This happens, because you're not escaping the variable "newepc" in your select query, mySql doesn't know it should be a variable.. you can try f-Strings or just normal concatination.